# debugging elasticsearch github project on intellij

Tags: elasticsearch, intellij-idea

I have cloned the elasticsearch github repo on my linux machine and i have java 8. I go to the directory elasticsearch and run the command "gradle build" . But it throws me error saying there is an error in : 
Build file '/home/tracxn-lp-354/Documents/sanchit/elasticsearch/benchmarks/build.gradle' line: 31

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':benchmarks'.

  > Failed to apply plugin [id 'elasticsearch.build']
  >   Java 1.9 or above is required to build Elasticsearch

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, you need to install a newer version of java.

What version of java does it say it's running?

```
java -version
```

If it doesn't say 1.9 then you need an upgrade!

```
sudo apt-get purge openjdk*
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java9-installer

java -version

sudo apt-get install oracle-java9-set-default
```

--

Once all this is done:

Make sure to open `Project Structure` in IntelliJ and navigate to:

`Project->Project SDK`.

Specify the latest version of the Java JDK (9) and click Apply.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure you installed **Java 9** (JDK 9 is required to build Elasticsearch).

Now, run the following command from Elasticsearch root directory (it automatically configures IDE):

```
gradle idea
```

After that, open Elasticsearch project from IntelliJ IDEA with enabled Gradle auto-import. This step is important, because it setups correct project structure for IDEA (content root, source folders, etc):

```
File -> New -> Project from Existing Sources... -> Import Gradle Project
```

And make sure that Project SDK is set to the Java version 9.

Now, to debug Elasticsearch, go to the `Run -> Edit Configurations` menu and add the following configurations:

[image]

Add breakpoint somewhere, for example in:

```
server/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/bootstrap/Elasticsearch.java
```

And run Debug 'Elasticsearch' (Shift + F9 in IntelliJ IDEA).

**P.S.** The process might be time consuming, so be patient and enjoy the result!